# How do I add new files/folders to an existing Github repository?

Tags: github

I'm new to Github, and have a repository that I have been using basically to backup code I have stored locally on a Linux computer and track the changes I make to the project. The structure of that project since I have started using Github is: `https://github.com/username/Project/tree/master/Folder1`. I have been performing all of my add/commit/push commands in a Linux terminal in `Folder1`, and it has worked well. Now I am trying to create a `Folder2` and add this to my project.

In linux, I duplicated `Folder1` and renamed it `Folder2`. I then did `git add Folder2` in the Project folder, which seemed to work fine, but then I looked on my Github repository to see that `Folder2` is completely empty. I then went into `Folder2` on Linux to try to perform an add/commit/push, but the push was unsuccessful.

When a try to push from within Folder2, I get the following error:
    `no such identity: (url to id_github-rsa)
    no such identify: (url to id_github-rsa)
    Permission denied (public key).
    fatal Could not read from remote repository.
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) is purely local (no effect on the remote GitHub repository)

Only a commit+push would have any effect.

Check your `git remote -v` in `Folder1` and `Folder2` in order to see what URL you are using.
You should have a `~/.ssh/config` file which helps referencing the right key.

If you are pushing to *one* GitHub repository, then your local folders should be the same as your intended target structure, meaning:

```
Folder1
Folder2
```

Two folders (not one renamed into the other)

---

The OP adds:

> When I run `git remote -v` in `Folder1` I get my result as:
>
> ```
> origin https://github.com/username/Project.git (fetch)
> ```
>
> whereas the same command in `Folder 2` gives
>
> ```
> origin git@github.com:username/Project.git (fetch) instead.
> ```

It would be better to use the same URL:

```
 cd Folder2
 git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/Project.git
```

However, it would also be preferable to save `Folder2` to its own GitHub project rather than trying to reuse "`Project.git`"

---

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart.
```

That is expected because both Folder1 and Folder2 are on the same branch (master) but with different history (check `git log` output)

The simplest way to achieve what you want is to have a struct like:

```
cd /local/path/to/

git init myProjects (new empty folder)
git remote add origin https://github.com/<me>/myProjects (new empty repository)
mkdir Folder1
mkdir Folder2
# copy the files to their relevant folders
git add . (from `/local/path/to/myProjects`)
git commit -m "Folder1 and 2"
git push -u origin master
```

So *one* repository, with one branch (`master`), but intermixed history (some commits will be for Folder1, or 2, or both)

Easy to restore: on a new machine

```
cd /local/path/to
git clone https://github.com/<me>/myProjects
```

---

To keep the existing Folder1 history:

```
cd /local/path/to
mv Projects Projects.old
mv Projects.old/Folder1 Projects
cd Projects
mkdir Folder1
git mv * Folder1
git add .
git commit -m "Move Folder1"
mkdir Folder2
# copy files into Folder2
git add .
git commit -m "Folder2"
git push
```

Comment: When I run `git remote -v` in `Folder1` I get my result as: `origin https://github.com/username/Project.git (fetch)` whereas the same command in `Folder 2` gives `origin git@github.com:username/Project.git (fetch)` instead. Is this the issue?

Comment: @JamesArnold Yes, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I ran the `git remote set-url origin` command and then tried again to push to Project.git, but both got an error that it failed and got this result: `hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: @JamesArnold Exactly. That is why I recommend creating a second empty repository on GitHub, dedicated for Folder2.

Comment: Is there no way for me to fix this error without creating a new repository? I don't understand what the error is saying.

Comment: @JamesArnold your new repository Folder 2 has a different history than folder 1: you could try and checkout an orphan branch, and pushing that new branch: that would work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195026/discussion-between-james-arnold-and-vonc).